# Order of elements in certain generating sets of non-abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

The following example is just to clarify the idea.

**Example:**
The dihedral group has the following presentation $$D_{2i}=\left<s,r/s^2=r^i=e,sr=r^{-1}s \right>$$
 Let $S_1=\{s,r\}$,  $S_2=\{s,sr\}$.

Note that $D_{2i}=\left<S_1 \right>=\left<S_2\right>$

Order of $D_{2i}$ is $2i$.    Elements order of $S_1$ are respectively 2, $i$. Both elements  of $S_2$ have order 2.  Thus the  elements order of $S_2$ is independent from the order of $D_{2i}$ (or equal 2 for any  $D_{2i}$).

My question: Is this true for any **non-abelian** group family?

In otherwords, if $G$ is finite non-abelian group family, can we find  generating set of $G$, such that the order of its elements  is independent from the order of $G$.

Note that: The above property is  not true for the abelian case.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the orders of generators being "independent" from the order of the group (at least to me). Certainly if $G$ is finite, then Lagrange etc. tell us *something* about the order of the generators.

Comment: @pjs36  "Independent" means: the order of the elements (in the generating set) is upper bounded by the certain constant for any order of $G$.

Comment: @pjs36 yes we must suppose that $G$ is  finite non-abelian group family

Comment: If you mean "There exists some constant $N$ such that we can generate any finite nonabelian group using elements of order at most $N$", then this is false. In particular, nonabelian $p$-groups exist for all $p$, like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p). But I still suspect I don't really understand the question, so I'll probably leave it alone.